# Can I create an error ticket in web2py without showing an error page, for a specific action?

Tags: web2py

I'd like to add an error ticket to the errors log in web2py, but still return a custom page. Is there a way to do this -- action-specific errors of some kind?

If you want to return a static error per app, you can redirect to an HTML page -- see [here](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/04#Routes-on-error) for docs and a routes.py example:

```
routes_onerror = [
  ('init/400', '/init/default/login'),
  ('init/*', '/init/static/fail.html'),
  ('*/404', '/init/static/cantfind.html'),
  ('*/*', '/init/error/index')
]
```

Any way to do this per action though?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first link you provided, [`routes_onerror`](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/04#Routes-on-error) is not limited to returning static error pages. The error route specified can be a web2py action that generates a dynamic response. As noted in the documentation, the error action will receive the HTTP status code, error ticket identifier, and originally requested URL in the query string. So, a ticket will be generated, but the user will see whatever custom HTML response is returned by the error handling action.

If the concern is with just a single controller action, though, another option is simply to use standard Python error handling facilities:

```
def myaction():
    try:
        [do something]
        return response.render(dict(...))
    except:
        [create error response]
        response.status = 500
        return error_response # or raise HTTP(500, error_message)
```

Comment: Thanks! If I use routes.py to map 500s to an action, I'd be mapping 500s for the whole app. I could make that work with conditional code for the specific action I'm interested in dealing with, but it feels like an anti-pattern to have page-specific error handling code in a single global action.

Comment: In a production application, typically one would replace the default error page (which simply displays a ticket link that is inaccessible to the user) with a custom error page. So, routing all errors (of a particular type) to a single handler (which can then route to further logic depending on the particular error source) seems like a reasonable pattern to me. But if you really just want special error handling for a single action, it is simple enough to use a standard `try/except` block to catch any errors.

Comment: Ideally I want to (1) record the exception as a web2py ticket, (2) show a special error response to the user for that page, and (3) do that without special case code in the error handler. The above solution gets (2) and (3) without (1), and using a special error route gets (1) and (2) without (3). Appreciate the suggestions though.